# ASP - how to remove single quote from user input text

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

```
answer  = Request.Form("Text" & i)
```

In a form a user inputs random text which is inserted into a database. Currently if the user puts in single quotes it creates an error. How do i remove just single quotes' from the users answer?

Comment: Instead of removing the single quotes, why don't you figure out how to include them properly? They are part of the text. If you pass the user's input in a parameter to your SQL or stored procedure, you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answer was to use ... Replace(answer, "'", "")

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
answer.Replace("\'", "");
```

The above will replace the Single quote.

Comment: answer = answer.Replace("\'", "")  ...?

Comment: ya definately string class has replace method.

Comment: You shouldn't use C# type escaping in VB code, and there is no need to escape the apostrophes anyway. `answer.Replace("'", "")`

Comment: internal server error, meaning error in code of syntax i belive

Comment: Are you using C#.net Its working fine in My system Double check with Debug

Comment: Then Use answer.Replace("'", "");

Answer (score 3):

Right way to solve this problem is use parameters when inserting to database.
instead of:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('" + answer + "')");
```

use

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (@answer)",answer);
```

Answer (score 2):

`'` are escaped by doubling, i.e replacing `'` with 2 x `'` for example `"Ralph''s".`

However you are **far** better off using parametrized statements with [command objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953.aspx) which will take care of that for you.

Comment: That specific escaping only works with some specific databases, each database have different rules for escaping string literals. You have to know what database is used to escape strings correctly.

Comment: Good point, I shouldn't have assumed an MS db, another plus for parametrized statements.